# can someone give an example of C++ condition_varible where the thread A that notifies thread B has to respond after thread B is notified?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, condition-variable

For example, suppose thread B is waiting on a condition variable and thread A notifies thread B. After waked up, thread B does something and then notify A so that A will do something. I need this because I need to update the GUI in thread A if thread B does something. The below code is a skeleton of what I have in mind. However, I worry that threadB may notify A before thread A enters the waiting phase. Is this a legitimate concern? What do people usually do in this case? All the examples of condition_variable that I can find online doesn't have the situation where the notifying thread has to do something that depends on the notified thread.

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cond;

void threadA(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
    cond.notify_one();
    cond.wait(guard, [&](){return some bool expression;})
    // do something//
}

void threadB(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
    cond.wait(guard, [&](){return some bool expression;})
    // do something//
    cond.notify_one();
}
```

Comment: Could you specify what `some bool expression` really is? And, how is this condition set in the notifying threads? It may be quite important for answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you can try.

```
   std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cond;
    bool flag1 = false;
    bool flag2 = false;
    
    void threadA(){
        {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
        flag1 = true;
        cond.notify_one();
        }
    
        {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
        while(!flag2)
            cond.wait(guard, [&](){return some bool expression;})
        // do something//
        }
    }
    
    void threadB(){
        {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
        while(!flag1)
            cond.wait(guard, [&](){return some bool expression;})
        // do something//
        }
    
        {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
        flag2 = true;
        cond.notify_one();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `std::atomic_flag` to know when `A` enters the waiting phase. don't use a normal flag to avoid data races.

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cond;
std::atomic_bool a_has_entered = false;

void threadA(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
    cond.wait(guard, [&](){a_has_entered = true;return some_bool_expression;});
    // do something//
}

void threadB(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
    // do something//
    while(!a_has_enterd);
    cond.notify_one();
}
```

Or use another `conditon_variable` to avoid leaking the resources, as follows

```
std::mutex mtx, a_has_entered_guard_mtx;
std::condition_variable cond;
std::condition_variable cond_a_has_entered;
bool a_has_entered = false;

void threadA(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
    cond.wait(guard, [&](){std::lock_guard guard {a_has_entered_guard_mtx};
                a_has_entered = true;
                cond_a_has_entered.notify_all();
                return some_bool_expression;});
    // do something//
}

void threadB(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
    // do something//
    std::unique_lock a_has_entered_guard {a_has_entered_guard_mtx};
    cond_a_has_entered.wait(a_has_entered_guard, [&](){return a_has_entered;});
    cond.notify_all();
}
```